# Are there any auto-antonyms in Esperanto?

Tags: language

English abounds in [auto-antonyms](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/vorto-auto-antonym.html). Are there any in Esperanto?

Comment: That link leads to a 404 "not found" error page for me.

Comment: And please explain what you mean by auto-antonym, as there seem to be multiple conflicting definitions/meanings of that term.

Answer (score 19):

Laŭ mi, *krom* estas tia vorto. El [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/aliaj_rolvortetoj/krom.html):

> *Krom* montras aferon, kiun oni konsideras aparte. Tiu baza signifo donas praktike du signifojn: **escepta *krom*** kaj **aldona *krom***. La diferenco inter tiuj du signifoj estas tre granda, kaj tio iafoje povas krei **riskon de miskompreno**.

Kaj jen ekzemplo por rekta komparado, el PMEG:

> **Escepta *krom***
>
> *Tie estis ĉiuj miaj fratoj krom Petro.*<sup>LR.106</sup> Petro ne estis tie.
>
> **Aldona *krom***
>
> *Krom Petro tie estis ankaŭ ĉiuj aliaj miaj fratoj.*<sup>LR.106</sup> = Aldone al Petro ankaŭ ili estis tie.

Comment: Bonega respondo, kaj mi suprenvoĉdonis ĝin – sed mi atendos iom da tempo antaŭ ol akcepti ies ajn respondon:)

Comment: Ŝajnas al mi, ke ankaŭ ‘apenaŭ’ estas tia.

Comment: http://lernu.net/eo/forumo/temo/23085